# FFmpeg command line with option tee muxer, output to video file, and image2 muxer at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg, images, jpeg, avi, tee

I would like to save still images from a video, which is on a direct http URL. At the same time I want to save the video as well. How can I use ffmpeg with its special tee muxer to save the images and the video at the same time?
My attempt doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i http://www.example.com/video.avi -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -f tee 'video.avi|[f=image2]%06d.jpg'
```

Of course this only a simplified example, or else I could use the standard linux filter / command tee, but in real I want the video data go through ffmpeg for additional video / audio filtering in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The `tee` muxer is intended for use when you wish to encode only once and re-use the encoded packets. When your various outputs can't use the same encoding output, the tee muxer isn't of use.

So,

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i http://www.example.com/video.avi \
       -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy video.avi \
       -map 0:v %06d.jpg
```

You may want to add `-q:v 1` to control the JPEG quality.

```
       -map 0:v -q:v 1 %06d.jpg
```